# Decrement operator not working in android studio

Tags: android, sqlite, decrement

I want to increase and decrease the price when I press the + and - button. Here, my price is increasing and + button is working fine. But, when I press - button only quantity is decreasing and the price is increasing. I have retrieved the product price from SQLite Database.

```
public class Sofa1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageSlider sofaslider1;
    ImageButton plusquantity,minusquantity;
    TextView quantitynumber,sofaname,sofaprice,sofadesc;
    Button addtocart;
    int quantity;
    int totalprice=0;
    public Uri mcurrentcarturi;
    boolean hasallrequiredvalues = false;
    DBHelper DB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sofa1);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }

        sofaname=findViewById(R.id.sofaname);
        sofaprice=findViewById(R.id.sofaprice);
        sofadesc=findViewById(R.id.sofadesc);
        plusquantity = findViewById(R.id.addquantity);
        minusquantity  = findViewById(R.id.subquantity);
        quantitynumber = findViewById(R.id.quantity);

        DB = new DBHelper(Sofa1.this);
        String Name = DB.getProductNamePrice("SELECT F_Name FROM Furniture WHERE F_Type = 'Sofa';");
        String Price = DB.getProductNamePrice("SELECT F_Price FROM Furniture WHERE F_Type = 'Sofa';");
        String Desc = DB.getProductNamePrice("SELECT F_Description FROM Furniture WHERE F_Type = 'Sofa';");
        sofaname.setText(Name);
        sofaprice.setText(Price);
        sofadesc.setText(Desc);

        plusquantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(quantity<5){
                    //sofaprice
                    int baseprice= Integer.parseInt(sofaprice.getText().toString());
                    quantity++;
                    displayquantity();
                    totalprice = baseprice * quantity;
                    String setnewprice = (String.valueOf(totalprice));
                    sofaprice.setText(setnewprice);
                }
            }
        });

        minusquantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    int baseprice= Integer.parseInt(sofaprice.getText().toString());
                    if(quantity>1) {
                        quantity--;
                        displayquantity();
                        totalprice = baseprice * quantity;
                        String setnewprice = (String.valueOf(totalprice));
                        sofaprice.setText(setnewprice);
                    }
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayquantity() {
        quantitynumber.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using this line of code to read the base price:

```
int baseprice= Integer.parseInt(sofaprice.getText().toString());
```

but that's not right. sofaprice contains the calculated price, not the base price.

What I would is:

- create a variable, int baseprice, initialize it at zero;
- when you read the base price from the database, set baseprice to that value:

  String Price = DB.getProductNamePrice("SELECT F_Price FROM Furniture WHERE F_Type = 'Sofa';");
  baseprice = Integer.parseInt(Price);
- when you increment or decrement the quantity, totalprice will be calculated using the baseprice at activity level. You do not need to read it again from the textview (and it would be a mistake to do so).

Comment: Hey thanks very much! Its working fine. You are my life savior for now :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, every time you click button, the price will take the current total price, not a single price. And each price is `totalPice * quantity` , the actual total price should be `singlePice * quantity`

So you should set unit price as global variables like

```
private int unitPrice;

...

String Price = DB.getProductNamePrice("SELECT F_Price FROM Furniture WHERE F_Type = 'Sofa';");
unitPrice = Integer.parseInt(Price)

...

plusquantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(quantity<5){
                    //sofaprice
                    quantity++;
                    displayquantity();
                    totalprice = unitPrice * quantity;
                    String setnewprice = (String.valueOf(totalprice));
                    sofaprice.setText(setnewprice);
                }
            }
        });

minusquantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(quantity>1) {
                        quantity--;
                        displayquantity();
                        totalprice = unitPrice * quantity;
                        String setnewprice = (String.valueOf(totalprice));
                        sofaprice.setText(setnewprice);
                    }


            }
        });
```